# Port Conflict with XAMPP Apache

Tags: php, asp.net, apache, iis, xampp

I've installed XAMPP (Apache, MySQL, FileZilla, Mercury, Tomcat) Control Panel to my Windows 7 Professional which has IIS (ASP Server Service) turned on. It fails to start the Apache server saying that PID 4 (IIS Service, probably) is blocking my access activate the server. I've looked into netstats that there are IP addresses that are under PID 4 and it turns out that when I open those they browser shows me the welcome page of IIS/ASP server.

**What could be the fix to this port conflict / port overriding of XAMPP's Apache Server to the IIS / ASP Server?**

It would be a great helped if answered and the answer make it work.

P.S.: I can't provide log data due to it saying that the logs for Apache are not found. It did not start from the moment ever since I've installed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the below article:

http://techbrij.com/setting-up-xampp-apache-iis-windows

you can use IIS and Xampp together by changing their port. by default both of them are listening 80 port and on the same local IP.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the location of apache file and find the "httpd-ssl.conf"
You will find it here
"C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra" My installing location is C drive. You may put the location drive

Then Edit "httpd-ssl.conf" by using notepad and find "Listen 443" and replace 443 to  4430 to the whole documents and save. After that restart the XAMPP and hopefully it will start.